# AngularJS passing data to bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-controller

I think I'm missing something but cannot figure what.
Basically I'm trying to pass an object to the modal like below, but instead of getting the passed object I gets null...so I think is a problem with the scope but I'm new in Angular and need some help.

Controller

```
app.controller("musicViewModel", function ($scope, $http, $location, $uibModal, $log) {

$scope.selected = null;

$scope.open = function (item) {

    $scope.selected = item;

    $log.info('Open' + $scope.selected); // get right passes object

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'musicViewModel',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.selected;
            }
        }
    });
};

$scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
};
});
```

View

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="musicViewModel">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {{ selected }} // always gets null
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'd suggest you to pass the `scope` of your own controller instead of passing same `controller` again, by doing that you can remove the `resolve` also.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    scope: $scope, //passed current scope to the modal
    size: 'lg'
});
```

Otherwise you need to create a new `controller` and assign that controller for `modal` while opening it.

Comment: @PankajParkar are you able to provide an example of the latter solution for providing a controller? I am having a hard time getting that to work. Here's my question that relates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350463/angular-uibmodal-resolve-unknown-provider

Comment: I think below answer should help you..anyways i will look into that.

Answer (score 24):

When you use resolve, the map is injected into the given controller.

I recommend that u use a different controller to handle the modal functionality (*[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)*).

I also recommend to use dependency injection to support minification of the code. [Step 5](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) on the Angular tutorial wil explain this.

A simplified example of the modal controller would be.

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('App');

    app.controller('musicDetailController',

                ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'items',
        function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

            $scope.items = items;

        }]);
}());
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Using separate controller will allow to manage the code properly.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass an object directly.

I've tried all the solutions above, but wasn't really satisfied. I've solved the issue by writing a simple parser that enables you to pass both `strings` and `objects` directly to the modal, through the provided resolve function.

```
app.controller('ModalController', ['$uibModal', '$scope', function ($uibModal, $scope) {

    // Initialize $modal
    var $modal = this;

    // Open component modal
    $modal.open = function (component, size, data) {

        // Init modal
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            component: component,
            size: size || 'md',
            resolve: parseResolve(data)
        });
    };

    // Parse the resolve object
    function parseResolve(data) {
        if (typeof data === 'string') {
            return {
                data: function() {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (typeof data === 'object') {
            var resolve = {};
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                resolve[key] = function() {
                    return value;
                }
            })
            return resolve;
        }
    }

}]);
```

---

**When usings strings**

Template:

```
<button ng-click="$modal.open('modalSomething', 'md', 'value'">
    Click
</button>
```

Component:

```
bindings: {
    resolve: '@'
}
```

---

**When using objects**

Template:

```
<button ng-click="$modal.open('modalSomething', 'md', {key1: value1, key2: value2})">
    Click
</button>
```

Component:

```
bindings: {
    resolve: '<'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the below code working:

```
this.OpenModal = function() {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            url: "/name?parameter=" + $scope.Object.ParamValue,
            templateUrl: 'views/module/page.html',
            controller: myController
        });
    }
```

Comment: you should include more information on how your answer solve the problem