# Angular Modal is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-directive

I am using Angular bootsrap modal service. version of ui-bootstrap is a`ngular-ui-bootstrap 1.3.3`. below is my code.

First on module , I have registered correctly.

```
var angularFormsApp = angular.module("angularFormsApp", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap"]);
```

then on angular controller , I have injected this directive correctly.

```
var loginController = function ($scope, $window, $routeParams, $uibModal, DataService)
```

then I am calling this modal by following code inside same controller

```
var onError = function (reason) {
            $scope.modalOptions.headerText = "Error";
            $scope.modalOptions.bodyText = reason.statusText;

            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: baseurl + 'app/ErrorMessages/PopUpErrorMessage.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            });
        };

        $scope.cancelForm = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
```

Now as you can see I have created separate html file for modal and below is html

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3>{{modalOptions.headerText}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>{{modalOptions.bodyText}}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Close"
            ng-click="cancelForm()" />
</div>
```

Now till here everything is working , I mean on error method , modal is showing but problem is its showing blank , even nothing happening on close button click.

There is no error in console of chrome browser. Here is screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Check the Network tab in Chrome dev tools to see if the modal template is retrieved correctly. Make sure your controller isn't registered as `LoginController` instead of `loginController`.

Comment: And pass the scope in the open function: `scope: $scope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Modal does not know about your controller's scope. Try changing to this:

```
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: baseurl + 'app/ErrorMessages/PopUpErrorMessage.html',
        scope: $scope
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your current controller variables try to change 
`controller: 'loginController'` to `scope: $scope`. It will pass current scope to the modal.

Similar problem was here: [AngularJS passing data to bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286851/angularjs-passing-data-to-bootstrap-modal)