# Pass data to Modal in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have to pass some data from a get to a Modal window, by eg. I use "item" for "response.data.item"...

```
$http.get(link).then(function (response) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'newsModal.html',
        controller: 'NewsModalInstanceCtrl',
        resolve: {
            item: function () {
                return response.data.item; // !! response undefined
            }
        }
    });
```

My problem is that the "response" is "undefined"... what is the right way to pass that parameter to the modal?

Edit: 
Is there another way that passing the $scope to the Modal controller...?
I would like to have only the moldal information in the modal window, not all the response data from the link...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS passing data to bootstrap modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286851/angularjs-passing-data-to-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: I already seen that post before asking this question. I would't like to pass the scope

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'newsModal.html',
    controller: 'NewsModalInstanceCtrl',
    resolve: {
        item: function () {
          $http.get(link).then(function (response) {
                 return response.data.item;
          }
        }
});
```

Comment: as the get is not a syncronous function, the Item is always empty because is too late...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to pass it into the function

```
$http.get(link).then(function (response) {

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'newsModal.html',
    controller: 'NewsModalInstanceCtrl',
    resolve: {
        item: function (response) {
            return response.data.item;
        }
    }
});
```

However, I have not tested this code.

Comment: does not recognize the "response" parameter in the function: angular.js:12798 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: responseProvider <- response